# In which language is the proto compiler (of google protocol buffers) written?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I would like to know in which language the "proto compiler" (the compiler used to generate source files from Java, Python or c++) is written? Is it maybe a mix of languages?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance
Horace

Comment: a side note: `protoc` can call exe plugins for custom languages, which then can then of course be written in any language as long as they meet the expected spec (stdin/stdout, I expect)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be written [in C++](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/index#google.protobuf.compiler). There's also documentation on [Java](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/index) and [Python](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/index) APIs, but those don't appear to contain the compiler itself (at least I don't see anything that's obviously the compiler in either case, though I didn't spend a whole lot of time looking for it either).

That said, I'm almost tempted to vote to close -- for most practical purposes, the language used to implement the compiler is basically a trivia question, irrelevant to actual use. There is, however, an entirely legitimate exception: if you're going to download and modify the compiler, knowing the language you'd need to work with could be quite useful.

Comment: Thanks jerry. But If one is thinking about writing a maven plugin for the proto compiler then it is also useful to know what language it is written in.

Answer (score 1):

The protoc compiler is written in C or C++ (its a native program anyway).

When I want to process proto files in java files, I

1. I use the protoc command to convert them to a Protocol Buffer File ie

   protoc protofile.proto --descriptor_set_out=OutputFile
2. Read the new protocol buffer file (its a FileDescriptorSet) and use it

An over complicated example is example, is  **compileProto** method in

http://code.google.com/p/protobufeditor/source/browse/trunk/%20protobufeditor/Source/ProtoBufEditor/src/net/sf/RecordEditor/ProtoBuf/re/display/ProtoLayoutSelection.java

its compilcated because options because the protoc command and options can be stored in a properties file.

**Note:** The **getFileDescriptor** method reads the newly created protocol buffer